# Pandas dataframe column subtraction, handling NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame for example

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(np.nan, .32), (.01, np.nan), (np.nan, np.nan), (.21, .18)],
                  columns=['A', 'B'])
        A   B
0   NaN     0.32
1   0.01    NaN
2   NaN     NaN
3   0.21    0.18
```

And I want to subtract column `B` from `A`

```
df['diff'] = df['A'] - df['B']

    A     B      diff
0   NaN   0.32   NaN
1   0.01  NaN    NaN
2   NaN   NaN    NaN
3   0.21  0.18   0.03
```

Difference returns NaN if one of the columns is `NaN`. To overcome this I use `fillna`

```
df['diff'] = df['A'].fillna(0) - df['B'].fillna(0)

    A     B      diff
0   NaN   0.32   -0.32
1   0.01  NaN    0.01
2   NaN   NaN    0.00
3   0.21  0.18   0.03
```

This solves `NaN` coming in the diff column, but for index 2 the result is coming to `0`, while I want the difference as `NaN` since columns A and B are `NaN`.

Is there a way to explicitly tell pandas to output `NaN` if both columns are NaN?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`Series.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html) with `fill_value=0` parameter:

```
df['diff'] = df['A'].sub(df['B'], fill_value=0)
print (df)
      A     B  diff
0   NaN  0.32 -0.32
1  0.01   NaN  0.01
2   NaN   NaN   NaN
3  0.21  0.18  0.03
```

If need replace NaNs to `0` add [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['diff'] = df['A'].sub(df['B'], fill_value=0).fillna(0)
print (df)
      A     B  diff
0   NaN  0.32 -0.32
1  0.01   NaN  0.01
2   NaN   NaN  0.00
3  0.21  0.18  0.03
```

Comment: Nice one, although there's a `NaN` at 2nd row. And I realized that it's what OP wants.

Comment: The original solution you wrote works `df['diff'] = df['A'].sub(df['B'], fill_value=0)` . If I chain `.fillna(0) ` to it I end up with bad output I am getting currently. If you could remove `fill_value=0` from answerI can mark this as solution.

Comment: can you please update the diff column of row 2 to 0 - which is the right output for the operation performed.